# In Xcode 15, the quality of the information during build and install has been reduced. Any clue on how to bring back the previous behaviour?

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode 15 I am developing a very large application (4Gb) and during the run process, this is what I see in the top middle toolbar:

[image]

In previous versions of Xcode, the toolbar displayed much more info like what file was being installed to the iPhone. Any clue on how to come back to the previous behaviour ? Thanks a lot